# Sharepoint CAML IN operator not working with FileDirRef

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, jsom

I want to retrieve a list of file from two folders.

When I combine two `<Eq><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />...` with `<Or>` it works fine.

When I want to use the `<In>` operator it returns no entries.

Narrowing it to one criteria:

- This returns the files from `/sites/intranet/dox`:

  ```
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where>
                              <Eq><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
                          <Value Type="Text">/sites/intranet/dox</Value>
                         </Eq></Where></Query></View>');
  ```
- I expect the same result with `<In>`, but I get no results:

  ```
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where>
                         <In><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
                           <Values>
                             <Value Type="Text">/sites/intranet/dox</Value>
                           </Values>
                         </In></Where></Query></View>');`
  ```

Is it a limitation due to the field FileDirRef?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'In' CAML tag scope only pertains to list FieldRefs see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625761(v=office.15).aspx